How to evaluate $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-x^2+2 x} \text{erf}(x+1) \, dx$
I am interested in evaluating:
$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-x^2+2 x} \text{erf}(x+1) \, dx$$
By using change of variable $x\to 1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}$, this is transformed into:
$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\infty } \frac{e \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)
   \text{erf}\left(2+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}} \, dy$$
Splitting about $0$ we get:
$$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^0 \frac{e \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right) \text{erf}\left(2+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}} \,
   dy+\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right) \text{erf}\left(2+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}
   \, dy$$
I could compute the second integral to be: $-\frac{1}{4} e \sqrt{\pi } \left(\text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2-2\right)$
However I do not know how to evaluate the first one.
Any help is appreciated.

Mathematica doesn't come up with a closed-form for this integral, so it's not evident to me that such a form must exist. (If the question is about how to numerically approximate the result it's a different matter.)

That said, Mathematica also can't verify the formula for the second term (in terms of erfc) and yet this does seem to be numerically correct. So in that respect this objection is not decisive.

The problem can be reduced to
$$I= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(\text{e}\pi -  f(1,1) - \frac{1}{\text{e}} f(2,\infty) \right), $$
where $f(a,b) = \int_0^b \text{e}^{-ax^2} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\text{d}x$.
These integrals look a bit more common, and following @Conreu's insight, they can actually be solved exactly (at least for the needed $b=1$ and $b=\infty$) -- see the second edit.
Now to show the above relation:
Write
$$I = \text{e} \int_{-1}^\infty \text{e}^{-x^2} \text{erf}(x+2)\text{d}x = \frac{2\text{e}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-1}^\infty \int_0^{x+2} \text{e}^{-x^2-y^2}\text{d}x\text{d}y.$$
Switching to polar coordinates with $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$ gives
$$I = \frac{2\text{e}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^\pi \int_0^{r(\phi)} \text{e}^{-r^2}r\text{d}r\text{d}\phi,$$
where the complexity of the integration region is hidden in $r(\phi)$.
The inner integral is trivial, and we get
$$I = \frac{\text{e}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\pi \left(1-\text{e}^{-r(\phi)^2} \right)\text{d}\phi. $$
Looking at the boundaries, we have
$$r(\phi) = \begin{cases} \infty & 0\le \phi < \pi/4 \\\\ \frac{2}{\sin(\phi)-\cos(\phi)} & \pi/4 < \phi < 3\pi/4 \\\\ \frac{1}{\cos(\phi)} & 3\pi/4 < \phi < \pi \end{cases}.$$
Thus,
$$I = \frac{\text{e}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left( \pi - \int_{3\pi/4}^\pi \text{e}^{-\sec(\phi)^2} \text{d}\phi - \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \text{e}^{-4[\sin(\phi) - \cos(\phi)]^{-2}} \text{d}\phi \right).$$
Some more trigonometry and substituting $x=\tan(\phi)$ in the first integral and $x=\cot(\phi)$ in the second one then gives the form stated above.
The numerical results for the three terms are
\begin{align*}
\text{e}\sqrt{\pi} &= 4.818029\dots,\\\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}f(1,1) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^1 \text{e}^{-x^2} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\text{d}x = 0.349133\dots,\\\\
\frac{1}{\text{e}\sqrt{\pi}}f(2,\infty) &= \frac{1}{\text{e}\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \text{e}^{-2x^2} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\text{d}x = 0.109611\dots,
\end{align*}
and $I=4.359285\dots$.
Edit: As requested, a few more details on the trigonometry: Note that $\sin(\phi)-\cos(\phi) = \sqrt{2} \sin(\phi-\pi/4)$, so the second integral is
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \text{e}^{-2\sin(\phi-\pi/4)^{-2}} \text{d}\phi = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \text{e}^{-2\csc(\phi)^{2}} \text{d}\phi.$$
Now use $\csc(\phi)^2=1+\cot(\phi)^2$ and substitute $x=\cot(\phi)$.
Edit2: Exact solutions for $f(a,b)$ for special $b$ (again, credit to @Conreu).
Let's start with $b=\infty$ and write $I(a)=f(a,\infty)$.
Then
$$I'(a) = -\int_0^\infty \text{e}^{-ax^2} \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\text{d}x = I(a) - \int_0^\infty \text{e}^{-ax^2}\text{d}x = I(a) - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.$$
The solution of this ODE is of the form $I(a)=c(a)\text{e}^a$, and inserting this yields $c'(a)\text{e}^a = - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$, which can readily be integrated to give
$$c(a)=c_0 - \frac{\pi}{2}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}).$$
Thus, we find $I(a) = \left(c_0 - \frac{\pi}{2}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}) \right) \text{e}^a$, and with $a=0$ giving $I(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we finally have
$$f(a,\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{erfc}(\sqrt{a}) \text{e}^a.$$
Similarly, for $I(a)=f(a,b=1)$, differentiating gives
$$I'(a) = -\int_0^1 \text{e}^{-ax^2} \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\text{d}x = I(a) - \int_0^1 \text{e}^{-ax^2}\text{d}x = I(a) - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \text{erf}(\sqrt{a}).$$
Using $\int \text{e}^{-x} \text{erf}(\sqrt{x}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erf}(\sqrt{x})$ and $I(0) = \frac{\pi}{4}$, we then find
$$f(a,1) = \frac{\pi}{4} \left(1 - \text{erf}(\sqrt{a})^2 \right) \text{e}^a.$$
Combining all the results gives the exact answer
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(\text{e}\pi -  \frac{\pi}{4} \left(1 - \text{erf}(1)^2 \right) \text{e} - \frac{1}{\text{e}} \frac{\pi}{2} \text{erfc}(\sqrt{2}) \text{e}^2 \right) \\\\
&= \text{e}\sqrt{\pi}\left( \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}(\sqrt{2}) + \frac{1}{4} \text{erf}(1)^2 \right) = 4.359285\dots
\end{align}
Edit3: Final edit, my intuition about the $f$-integrals was correct. These are actually known as Owen's T function, which are defined as
$$T(h,b) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^b \text{e}^{-\frac{1}{2} h^2 (1+x^2)}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \text{d}x,$$
and we have $f(a,b) = 2\pi \text{e}^a T(\sqrt{2a}, b)$.
The result then also follows from special cases of this function known in the literature.

I'm trying to come up with a semi-closed form for both your last integrals. I noticed you used $r(\phi)=\frac{1}{\cos\phi}$ instead of $r(\phi)=-\frac{1}{\cos\phi}$, are your calculations correct still?

Could you also provide how you did the substitution in the second integral step by step  please?

Oh, you're right, I didn't even think about the $\phi$ region. But this sign mistake cancels later on. Anyhow, the final result here is numerically identical to your original integral, so I'm fairly confident it is correct (modulo typos and other errors in the calculation...)

I finally fixed the minus sign problem. It's nice that you noticed the ODE method was also appliable to the first integral too, really nice!

I'm just gonna solve the last two integrals that @Noctis got to.
For the first integral we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}&=\sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left[\psi_0\left(\dfrac{n+1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)-\psi_0\left(\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}$$
Alternatively, we can expand $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ and get
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}&=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_0^1 x^{2n}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm d\alpha^n}\right|_{\alpha=1}\int_0^1 e^{-\alpha x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm d\alpha^n}\left[\dfrac{\text{erf}(\sqrt \alpha)}{\sqrt \alpha}\right|_{\alpha=1}
\end{aligned}$$
As for the second integral, let's start by defining the integral
$$I(\alpha)\equiv\int_0^\infty e^{\alpha x^2}\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}=e^{-\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{\alpha(1+x^2)}\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}$$
This way what we're looking for is computing $I(-2)$.
Let us proceed by differentiating wrt $\alpha$:
$$I'(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty e^{\alpha x^2}\,\mathrm dx-I=-\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2i}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}-I$$
Firstly we'll solve the homogeneous ODE yielding
$$I_h=I_0 e^{-\alpha}$$
and then we'll vary the parameter $I_0=I_0(\alpha)$ and substitute it in the ODE obtaining
$$I_0'e^{-\alpha}=-\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2i}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt \alpha}\implies I_0(\alpha)=-\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2i}\int\dfrac{e^\alpha}{\sqrt \alpha}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi\alpha}}{2i}\mathrm E_{\frac{1}{2}}(-\alpha)$$
Finally,
$$I(\alpha)=A e^{-\alpha}+\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi\alpha}}{2i}e^{-\alpha}\mathrm E_{\frac{1}{2}}(-\alpha)$$
Imposing the boundary condition $I(\alpha\to-\infty)=0$ we find $A$ has to be $0$ too. And thus,
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-2 x^2}\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}=I(-2)=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}e^2\mathrm E_{\frac{1}{2}}(2)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}e^2[1-\text{erf}(\sqrt 2)] $$

I think the rogue minus sign comes from some $\sqrt{-1}$ business; maybe the first $\text{i}$ should be a $-\text{i}$? Anyhow, your method to rewrite this as an ODE is beautiful, and it also works with the original integral (i.e. with $\text{e}^{-ax^2}$). This avoids any spurious $\text{i}$'s and gives the correct sign. I will think a bit more about the other integral, maybe a similar approach could work there too?

Ok I managed to also solve the other integral, I will edit my answer accordingly

Thank you all for sharing the nice analyses. I was able to evaluate the first integral in my original post.
First integral:
$$e \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^0 \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right) \text{erf}\left(2+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}} \,
   dy$$
Apply change of variable $z = -y$:
$$e \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right) \text{erf}\left(2-\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}} \, dz$$
This can now be computed using the algorithm presented in this paper:
A Special Case of a Bivariate Non-Central t-Distribution.
The answer is:
$$\frac{1}{4} e \sqrt{\pi } \left(\text{erf}(1)^2+\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2\right)$$
So, plugging back, the original integral is:
$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-x^2+2 x} \text{erf}(x+1) \, dx=\frac{1}{4} e \sqrt{\pi } \left(1+\text{erf}(1)^2+2
   \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$
The approximate numerical value is $4.35929$.

Interesting! I guess you don't really need a different answer then, but with the help of @Conreu I have also managed to obtain the same result via my more "elementary" approach. Maybe you'll find that useful too

@Noctis, the approach that you and Conreu presented are particularly interesting because of its "elementary" nature. Actually I did not check this post until I got the solution myself (when I came back to post an answer), so was not following your developments. I will accept your post as the answer.
